# BufferedReader returns ISO-8859-15 String - how to convert to UTF16 String?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have an FTP client class which returns InputStream pointing the file. I would like to read the file row by row with BufferedReader. The issue is, that the client returns the file in binary mode, and the file has ISO-8859-15 encoding.

Comment: I don't see how UTF-8 is involved here - Java uses UTF-16 internally, not UTF-8.

Comment: Sorry, it should have said UTF-16. Fixed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the file/stream/whatever really contains ISO-8859-15 encoded text, you just need to specify that when you create the InputStreamReader:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(ftp.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-15"));
```

Then `readLine()` will create valid Strings in Java's native encoding (which is UTF-16, not UTF-8).

Comment: I’m pretty sure that unless you use the form of the constructor that takes an encoder argument, not just a string or charset, you won’t get an exception on malformed input.

Comment: @tchrist: You're talking about the ISR constructor that takes a CharsetDecoder argument, right?  It's true all the other ctors create decoders that *replace* invalid characters instead of throwing exceptions.  But I don't think an ISO-8859-15 decoder would ever throw an exception anyway.  Every possible byte value maps to a valid character, and that's the only way it could detect malformed input.

Comment: Yes, that’s right. The problem is when you ask for UTF-8 and don’t get it — *and* don’t get an exception!! Similarly for output, if you (stupidly) default to the platform default encoding, which on the Mac at least replaces unmappable code points with `?` characters, again with neither warning nor exception. I’m used to a lot safer behavior with Perl in these areas, and the Java defaults are just plain broken. Our whole codebase (the Java part, not the Perl part) is riddled with nasty errors because of this. Almost makes you want to monkey-patch the std Java libs. *Almost*. ☺

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                            ftp.getInputStream(),
                            Charset.forName("ISO-8859-15")
                        )
                    );
String row = br.readLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

The original string is in ISO-8859-15, so the byte stream read by your InputStreamReader will be in this encoding. So read in using that encoding (specify this in the InputStreamReader constructor). That tells the InputStreamReader that the incoming byte stream is in ISO-8859-15 and to perform the appropriate byte-to-character conversions.

Now it will be in the standard Java UTF-16 format, and you can then do what you wish.

I think the current problem is that you're reading it using your default encoding (by not specifying an encoding in InputStreamReader), and then trying to convert it, by which time it's too late.

Using default behaviour for these sort of classes often ends in grief. It's a good idea to specify encodings wherever you can, and/or default the VM encoding via `-Dfile.encoding`

Comment: Must have been a misclick, sorry, it's left too late to undo :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader("ISO-8859-1"))
...
```

Comment: s/b ISO-8859-15, not ISO-8859-1